# iOS app - find (unknown) private api calls

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, iphone-privateapi

We have an app that's on iTunes, and it received a warning in iTunes that it uses undocumented api calls:

```
reateScreenIOSurface
IOSurfaceAcceleratorCreate
IOSurfaceAcceleratorTransferSurface
IOServiceGetMatchingService
IOMobileFramebufferOpen
IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface
kIOMasterPortDefault
IOServiceMatching
IOObjectRelease
IOServiceClose
```

These are all from [IOSurface api](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/IOSurfaceAPI_header_reference/Reference/reference.html), which is for Mac OSX, however, I can't find any of those cals in our app. My guess is that one of the third party frameworks that we're using is the problem.
The app has 3 frameworks that may use these apis: Aviary, Sincerely and Pritnzel.

Anyway, my question is, **how can I find where (and if) these apis are really used**?
I've used the `nm -u` and `otool -L` on the app binary, as well as on the 3 frameworks (and any other third party frameworks that the app uses), without any luck.

Many thanks

Comment: The easiest way would be to open binary with texteditor and search for `IOSurface.framework`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't even have to use nm or tool for this. Just use grep to search mentioning of these API's in frameworks directory.

However, that's strange that you can't find using nm and tool, especially in your binary.

BTW. Try to grep for "IOSurface" too. It's a framework which defines these methods.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to find it by searching through the build file in a text editor, in an older build.

Comment: By the way, the methods were used by the 'Lookback' framework, which was also left in the release build.